# Borel-Carathéodory theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to prove the Borel-Carathéodory theorem. One of the steps given is this:

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, $a_n \in \mathbb C$, $A(r)= \sup_{|z|\leq r} \Re(f(z)) $ for $r \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Now suppose $f(0)=0$, using the fact that for $n\geq 1, r > 0$, $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi r^n}\int_0^{2\pi} \Re(f(re^{i\theta})) \ e^{-in\theta} d\theta$,

show that $|a_n| \leq \frac{2A(r)}{r^n}$.

By simply putting the modulus inside the integral, it is easy to show that $|a_n| \leq \frac{2 \sup_{|z| \leq r} |\Re(f(z))| } {r^n}$, but I can't get rid of the absolute value.